# How to change a symbolic link to a directory to another target?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

```
# ln -sv /path/to/target /path/to/link
‘/path/to/link’ -> ‘/path/to/target’
```

Now I want to replace that target with target2:

```
# ln -sfv /path/to/target2 /path/to/link
‘/path/to/link/target2’ -> ‘/path/to/target2’
```

Whoa! What happened there? Trailing slashes have no effect whatsoever:

```
ln -sfv /path/to/target2/ /path/to/link
‘/path/to/link/target2’ -> ‘/path/to/target2/’

# ln -sfv /path/to/target2/ /path/to/link/
‘/path/to/link/target2’ -> ‘/path/to/target2/’

# ln -sfv /path/to/target2 /path/to/link/
‘/path/to/link/target2’ -> ‘/path/to/target2’
```

How to achieve `’/path/to/link’ -> ’/path/to/target2’` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `-n`/`--no-dereference` ("treat LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a directory"):

```
$ ln -sv /var/log /tmp/my-link
‘/tmp/my-link’ -> ‘/var/log’
$ ln -sfnv /var/opt /tmp/my-link
‘/tmp/my-link’ -> ‘/var/opt’
```

That is, `ln -s target link` will work like `ln -s target link/target` *if `link` links to a directory*.

Most Linux command tools will try to dereference symbolic links before applying their action, otherwise symbolic links would be mostly just confusing and almost useless. I guess the original `ln` authors thought consistency was more important than a certain amount of simplicity (with the risk of being confusing to people used to other tools) in this case.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Extra thanks for the explanation, as it all makes perfect sense now too!

Answer (score 2):

l0b0's answer is a good one.  It's simple, and that makes it the best for command line use most of the time.  In some cases though, you might care that it's not atomic.  `ln -sf` first deletes the old symlink, then creates the new one, so there's a brief period where no symlink exists.

If there's a need to be careful, you are better off to create the new symlink in a temporary location, and then `mv` it into place.

There's a ruby implementation of that here: http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2005-08-22-how-to-change-symlinks-atomically.html. It'd be easy to implement in any language though.  Beats me why it's not the default behaviour of ln.